# Source Transformation (complex circuit)

Tags: homework, source

In this exercise I need to find I using source-transformation. This task should be easy because s-t I a simple concept.

The problem for me here is that I have some voltage sources in parallel with the resistors and a current source in series with a resistor.

How should I proceed with source transformation? Could you tell which transformations should I do here?

Thanks,
Claudio Carbone

[image: Exercise figure]

Comment: Do you think the \$9\:\Omega\$ resistor in any way affects the current **I**? Or anything else? What about the \$3\:\Omega\$ resistor in series with the \$2\:\text{A}\$ current source? Isn't a current source \$\infty\:\Omega\$? How much does that resistor add to it? That's just for starters....

Comment: @jonk I don't know how the 9Ω resistor could affect the current I, but I don't think I coud just remove it, right? About the 3Ω resistor in series with the 2A current source I'm not sure what you mean by ∞Ω

Comment: Look. You have a solid 9 V on the left side of the 2 Ohm resistor. You can swap the 3 V with the 2 Ohm resistor (they are in series.) So you have a solid 9 V - 3 V = 6 V at the left end of the 2 Ohm resistor. So all the rest on the right side just boils down to 3 different voltages, via three different resistances, to a common node. It's really easy.

Comment: If you need further help, I'll try. But it's really simple. You have three voltages, +6 V, +10 V, and -4 V. And three resistors, 2 Ohm, 2 Ohm, and 9 Ohm. The central node is then 6.8 V. The difference between that and -4 is 10.8 V. That, divided by 9 Ohm is just I = 1.2 A. Which is the answer. The whole thing just falls apart, quickly. But I'll write it up if you cannot see it.

Comment: @jonk I mostly understood how to do it now, but the thing is... I didn't know i could swap a resistor and a voltage source if they are in series (can I do it with a current source too?) . I also didn't get how can i sum the 9V and the 3V voltage sources if they are not directly in series, but I might understand because If I had to use KCL there ti would be 9V - 3V which is equal to 6V as you said.

Comment: Look at the schematic. Make the bottom wire 0 V. (You can just do that.) Then the voltage at the left side of the 2 Ohm resistor is +9 V. Does the 9 Ohm resistor affect that? No. Does the 2 A current source and the 3 Ohm resistor affect that? No. So they don't matter. Throw them away. Now swap the 3 V supply that is in series with the 2 Ohm resistor (this affects nothing important at all.) Obviously, there is +6 V on one end of the 2 Ohm resistor now. Yes? You have +10 at the bottom end of another 2 Ohm.  Combine the 3 Ohm and 6 Ohm resistors = 9 Ohm, move the -4 V down, and that's it.

Comment: @jonk I still think it's crazy that i can just remove the 9Ω and the 2A from the circuit. I also wanted to tell you that I needed to use source transformation (written in the exercise)  so maybe this is the fastest way to solve it but not what my teacher intended to. Anyway now that I know I can swap things and remove things I will try to solve it with a little of s-t too. Thanks for your help (I have the exam in 2 hours lol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have used the schematic editor that is available here. (If you have a PC, that is. If just a cell phone then the photograph is forgiven.) It helps all of us to have labeled parts on the schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feDUmm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We can assign any one node to \$0\:\text{V}\$ at our whim. So I'm picking the bottom node:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSozZk.png)</sup>

Now, anything in-series can be swapped around without affecting the result. Plus, I can replace voltage sources with simple labels (it helps readability.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f92jwi.png)</sup>

Who cares about the left side part of the right side schematic?? It has no impact at all on the right side. So, really, all you have left is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9xVbh.png)</sup>

This is trivial, now. You have a voltage difference of \$12\:\text{V}\$ and a total of \$10\:\Omega\$ (the series sum of the three resistors.) Anyone can now figure out that \$I=1.2\:\text{A}\$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a simple statement about voltage and current sources in parallel or series might help: -

- A voltage source in parallel with a resistor appears to be a pure voltage source for any other connected components.
- A current source in series with a resistor appears to be a pure current source for any other connected components.
- A voltage source in parallel with a current source - the voltage source wins hence it defines the terminal voltage.
- A voltage source in series with a current source - the current source wins hence it defines the terminal current.